# How do you clear algolia's search query cache?

Tags: algolia

I've been using algolia with PHP and you can update/save objects using with the `addObjects` or `saveObjects` method on the client.

My problem is after you submit a bulk of objects to be saved and they update in the algolia database, if you do a search query for a keyword that used to be inside an attribute that has since been changed the results still show that object despite the data being updated. After clicking edit you can see the data on the `browse` page with the changes, but for whatever reason it still shows the results.

I tried closing/restarting the browser because ont he javascript side it's supposed to be in memory by default cache, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I tried using "refresh index" in the admin panel for algolia as well as calling clearCache on the javascript library and nothing is cleared. Same cached results based on old attribute data. I've even deleted the full index and resumitted all the objects and still got the same results.

**So how exactly do you clear the search query cache after object attributes have been successfully updated in the algolia database?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this isn't a coding or api issue, if you so happen to have a synonym set in algolia's admin panel what happens is when you search for a term like "foo" and you have an alias in the admin panel that says "bar" is a synonym for "foo" any objects you have in the database that has "bar" in any attribute value will be listed for terms "foo" because algolia goes in and replaces all values that matches that synonym then does a query for the term you're looking for and then you'll get unexpected results if you aren't careful.